What's so funny in Dom's words?
At a beach party scene in Fast X (2023), Isabel arrives in a sleek sports car, catching Dom’s attention. He questions her car’s modifications, specifically an RB26 engine. Isabel counters, stating an L24 engine can’t handle such boost. Despite Dom’s friend’s agreement, Isabel insists she doesn’t need validation.:

Isabel: It would have felt good to beat him
Dom: You and everyone here.
(people laughs)

What's so funny in Dom's words?

After reviewing the scene, I think the answer for why most of the crowd laughed is, "The script called for laughter."  I myself did not find Dom's retort particularly funny, so I don't have an in-universe explanation for the laughter.

From the viewpoint of telling the story, however...
The beach party has been going on, and Isabel, the sister of Elena, who was killed, has been street racing against other partygoers and winning.  Diogo, a good friend of Dom's is also at the party.  Dom arrives and Diogo greets him warmly, shouting that Dom is the reason everyone is there (racing and having a good time).
Isabel drives up, celebrating her latest racing triumph and begins taunting Dom, challenging him to race her.  This is the point in the scene where the dialog you asked about takes place.  Isabel wants to race, but Dom does not.  Isabel taunts Dom loudly in Portuguese and English, playing to the crowd of people around them, and Dom speaks back to her calmly, saying he's not there to race.  She is trying to antagonize him into racing her, and he's trying to calm her down.  This is when the two lines you quoted are spoken, and the crowd laughs.
The next thing that happens is the rumble of a car is heard, driving through the crowd toward them.  Everyone turns to look.  It's Dante, who has been targeting Dom for revenge, and who Dom has come to the party to find.

So the flow of the scene is that Dom has come to the party to find his enemy Dante, but first he encounters his two friends, Diogo and Isabel.  The dialogue between Dom and his friends needs to establish his mood and his intentions, and then it needs to quickly shift everyone's focus to Dante.  The way the script does this is by defusing Isabel's challenge with a wisecrack that makes the bystanders laugh.  The screenplay simply isn't very skillful at giving Dom something funny to say.
